# count showing keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I am vey new to sql.
I encountered a question while practicing
Find the difference between the total number of CITY entries in the table and the number of distinct CITY entries in the table.
The STATION table is described as follows:
[image: table structure]

I wrote this as answer:

```
select (select count(city) from station)-
(select distinct count(city) from station)
from station;
```

and this error is being shown(below).

```
select (select count(city) from station) (select distinct count(city) from station)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

why such an error?

Comment: @eshirvana this is the only table in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error because your client isn't running quite what you intended.

[From the SQL*Plus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-B8C7A924-216F-4E40-8D8C-0D27DE36EF96) (but it applies to SQL Developer too; though not SQLcl):

> You can continue a long SQL*Plus command by typing a hyphen at the end of the line and pressing Return. If you wish, you can type a space before typing the hyphen.

So when you entered your statement as three lines:

```
select (select count(city) from station)-
(select distinct count(city) from station)
from station;
```

the client actually saw it as two:

```
select (select count(city) from station) (select distinct count(city) from station)
from station;
```

You can see that in the error report:

```
select (select count(city) from station) (select distinct count(city) from station)
*
ERROR at line 1:
```

The trailing `-` was treated as a continuation character, and not as a minus operator.

To avoid that you could put it on one line yourself:

```
select (select count(city) from station)-(select distinct count(city) from station)
from station;
```

or just move the minus to the start of the following line:

```
select (select count(city) from station)
-(select distinct count(city) from station)
from station;
```

---

Not directly related, but because your overall query is `from station`, your result set will have one row for every row in that table, all with the same calculated difference. If you actually had to subtract the result of two subqueries you could do it against the single-row `dual` table instead:

```
select (select count(city) from station)
-(select distinct count(city) from station)
from dual;
```

But in this case, as @eshirvana already showed, you don't need the subqueries at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
select count(city) - count(distinct city)
from station;
```